# How do I keep my paragraphs separate?

Tags: php, explode, spaces, implode

I am writing a word limit function for my custom blog.  I want to limit the words on the index page and remove any formatting.  At the moment my code is:

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
  // Check if the string is too long
  $text=strip_tags($string);
  $words=explode(" ", $text);
  $size=sizeof($words);

  // Run the script
  if ($size >= $word_limit){
    return implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, $word_limit).' <a href="#">Read more ...</a>');
  }
  else { return $text; }
}
```

It works great, unless I have more than one paragraph.  If my first paragraph is, say, 20 words and my limit is 50, it will strip the tags and the spaces, but then will bring the last word of the first paragraph and the first word of the second paragraph together as one word.  Is there a way to make sure that the paragraphs have spaces between them?  I am a novice, so if it is a simple solution, do tell me that it is that simple and I shall lock myself in the cellar until it sinks in.  Or something similar.

Comment: Put paragraph text in `p` tag & style accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the html-source, probably your text has Newline as delimiter between paragraphs, which doesn't mean much for html. And debug: Print out the array of words, look at the paragraph limit. The newline sign is no space " ", so it stays "one word".

If it is a newline, search-replace it by `<br/>` for showing in html or use paragraphs.

Comment: That has solved my problem - my code (pulled from my database) had gone onto one line.  It has higlighted another issue - keeping my lines separate when I call them in my editor.  That doesn't seem to play ball.

Comment: Well, part of the honour goes to Rikesh, I just unzipped his comment. ;-)